# Trying to make a pi approximation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, pi, taylor-series

Ok so I am trying to approximate pi according to the number of terms in the taylor expansion you provide to the function . However I am getting many errors last of which is Cannot infer instance :

here is my code :

```
pie :: Rational -> Rational
pie n = 4.0 * (pie_h n 1.0)

pie_h :: Rational -> Rational
pie_h x y = if(x==0) then 0.0 
             else if ((y mod 2.0)/=0) then (1.0/y)+ pie_h (x-1.0) (y+2.0)
             else (-1.0/y)+(pie_h (x-1.0) (y+2.0))
```

Comment: You should post the actual compiler error, as well as what you don't understand about the error. Have you searched SO for the same error message and tried to apply the answers there? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhaskell%5D+%22cannot+infer+instance%22 ?

Comment: The type of pie_h takes two arguments, but the type you give only has one. You are using "mod", which requires Integral types but you are in a rational context.

Answer (score 1):

The type signature is wrong. You say that `pie_h` is a function that takes a single argument, a `Rational`, and returns a `Rational`, but then define it as a function that takes two arguments, `x` and `y`.

```
pie_h :: Rational -> Rational -> Rational
pie_h x y = ...
```

You can also simplify this a little with pattern matching and factoring out the only thing that varies, the sign of the first term.

```
pie_h 0 _ = 0.0
pie_h x y = (if even y then -1 else 1) / y + pie_h (x - 1.0) (y + 2.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the [Leibniz's formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Leibniz_formula_for_%CF%80) for pi, it's not going to converge for any practical value on n.

Regardless of the efficiency you can implement it in a more straightforward way

Define an invert function `(\x->1/x)` and alternate sum function (x1-x2+x3...)

For example,

```
import Ratio

invert :: Integer -> Rational
invert x = 1%x

altsum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
altsum [] = 0
altsum (x:xs) = x - altsum xs
```

Now, combining the two with the odd number series

```
fromRational $ (*) 4 $ altsum $ take 100 $ map invert [1,3..]
```

gives

```
3.131592903558553
```

You can define your approx_pi function as

```
approx_pi n = (fromRational . (*) 4 . altsum . take n . map invert) [1,3..]
```